# Looping through array of filenames in bash and read them

Tags: bash, tcsh

I have an array that contains paths of files. Each of these files has a single line.
I would like to loop through the array, and for each file read the line in it and store it in a variable. 
I tried this

```
f1=$1
f2=$2
filenames[0]=${f1}
filenames[1]=${f2}
for filename in "${filenames[@]}"
do
  # get the filename
  set fl = `basename $filename`
  echo ${fl}
  # read its contents (one line)
  set filecontent = `cat ${fl}`
  echo ${filecontent}
done
```

both echos display blank spaces. If I do

```
echo `basename $filename`
```

it does display the filename.
What is wrong with the loop above?

Comment: The first, second, and last lines of your code look like bash syntax, not tcsh.

Comment: They seem to work though. If I try `foreach filename ($filenames) end` I get `syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: `echo $tcsh` gives `6.18.01`

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're *not* running your script with tcsh. Do you have a `#!` line at the top of your script? How exactly are you invoking it? (I presume this isn't the entire script, since you haven't shown us how `$filenames` is set).

Comment: Did you run `echo $tcsh` at your interactive prompt or in your script?

Comment: I modified the question to how to do it in bash.

Comment: `fl=$(basename "$filename")` and  `filecontent=$(<"$fl")` , although `filecontent=$(< "${filename##*/}")` should do all of them.

Comment: @Jetchisel `fl=$(basename "$filename")` works but `filecontent=$(<"$fl")` does not. It gives me `filecontent:command not found`.

Comment: It works on this side though.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes it does on this side now too. Is there a way to get just the first line of `$(<"$fl")`?

Comment: `filecontent=$(head -n1 < "$fl")`

Comment: If you're using bash, then (a) delete the tcsh tag from your question, and (b) bash's `set` command isn't how you set variables. Your first `set` command should probably be `fl="$(basename "$filename")"`. Run `help set` in bash to see what bash's `set` command wants (but you don't want to use it here).

Comment: For example, in bash `set x = 42` is perfectly valid, but sets `$1` to `x`, `$2` to `=`, and `$3` to `42`. There's no special significance to the `=`, and it doesn't affect `$x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you seem to be mixing bash and tcsh syntax -- and just by chance you're using tcsh commands that happen not to be syntax errors in bash, but don't do what you want.

This:

```
set fl = `basename $filename`
```

is how you'd set `$fl` to the basename of `$filename` in tcsh. In bash, however, the `set` command is quite different. Since it's not what you need to use here anyway, I won't go into details, but you can read about them [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html).

In bash, the way to set a variable is just

```
var=value  # NO spaces around the "="
```

Also, bash, unlike tcsh, has a `$(command)` syntax to capture the output of a command, in addition to the older `` `command` ``.

So your command

```
set fl = `basename $filename`
```

should be

```
fl="$("basename $filename")"
```

Adding double quotes around both the `$filename` reference and the `$(...)` command substitution ensures that the shell can handle odd characters in the file name and/or command output.